# Gcm Notification only comes in my own device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I am new in Gcm and I want to send notification using gcm to my spacific users of my app but notification comes only in my own device

Here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String regid;
    CheckBox isdriver;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    String user_name = "";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    String TAG = "MainActivity";
    String SENDER_ID = "224163385438";
    String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCL3REK_ONEgLdhcP8giso_5P6xWE3gUvA";
    Utils utils;
    private Context context = MainActivity.this;
    private ProgressDialog pb;
    private EditText username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        utils = new Utils(this);
        isdriver = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.isDriver);

    }

    private void registerInBackground() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute : " + msg);

                if (!msg.equalsIgnoreCase("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE")) {

                    Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("server_response", msg);
                    msgObj.setData(b);
                    handler.sendMessage(msgObj);

                } else {

                    utils.showToast("Error : " + msg
                            + "\nPlease check your internet connection");

                    hidePB();

                }
            }

            // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and
            // update the progress
            private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    String aResponse = msg.getData().getString(
                            "server_response");

                    if ((null != aResponse)) {

                        Log.i(TAG, "    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();");

                        sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    } else {

                    }

                }
            };
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use
     * GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo
     * since the device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the
     * message using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    public void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

        Log.i(TAG, "sendRegistrationIdToBackend");

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    // yahan reg id ki server webserivcice dalegi

                    httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test5.luminativesolutions.com/cabbooking/ws/gcmdemo/save_reg_id.php");
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                            user_name));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id", regid));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                            responseHandler);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);

                    if (response != null) {

                        if (response
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("Username already registered")) {

                            utils.showToast("Username already registered");

                            hidePB();



                        } else {
                            if (response
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase("New Device Registered successfully")) {

                                utils.savePreferences(Utils.UserName, user_name);
                                // Persist the regID - no need to register
                                // again.
                                utils.storeRegistrationId(regid);

                                utils.showToast("Device registration successful");

                            }
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    hidePB();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnsave) {
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            user_name = username.getText().toString().trim();
            if (user_name.length() > 0) {

                Log.d(TAG, "startRegistration");

                showPB("Registering the device");

                startRegistration();
                /*if(isdriver.isChecked()){
                    Log.i(TAG,"Driver reg id");
                    Log.d(TAG, utils.getFromPreferences(user_name));

                }*/
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BookingActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("username",user_name);
                i.putExtra("regid",regid);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "Username empty");

            }
        }
    }

    void startRegistration() {

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
            // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
            Log.i(TAG, "Google Play Services OK");
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = utils.getRegistrationId();
            /*if(isdriver.isChecked()){
                utils.savePreferences(user_name, regid);
                Log.d(TAG,utils.getFromPreferences(user_name));
            }*/
            System.out.println(regid);
            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Reg ID Not Empty");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }

    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "No Google Play Services...Get it from the store.");
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void showPB(final String message) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                pb = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pb.setMessage(message);
                pb.show();
            }
        });

    }

    void hidePB() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (pb != null && pb.isShowing())
                    pb.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**BookingActivity.java**

```
public class BookingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    Utils utils;
    Intent i;
    static String TAG = "GCM DEMO";
    String user_name;
    String regid;

    String SENDER_ID = "224163385438";
    String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCL3REK_ONEgLdhcP8giso_5P6xWE3gUvA";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

        i = getIntent();

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                "CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"));
    }

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

            String message = b.getString("message");

            Log.i(TAG, " Received in Activity " + message + ", NAME = "
                    + i.getStringExtra("username"));


        }
    };

    public void onClick(final View view) {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.booking)) {

            sendMessage();

            //clearMessageTextBox();

        }

    }

    public void sendMessage() {

        final String messageToSend = "Driver you are now booked by: "+i.getStringExtra("username");

        if (messageToSend.length() > 0) {

            Log.i(TAG, "sendMessage");

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        httppost = new
                                HttpPost("http://www.test5.luminativesolutions.com/cabbooking/ws/gcmdemo/gcm_engine.php");
                        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                                messageToSend));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "registrationIDs", i.getStringExtra("regid")));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiKey",
                                API_KEY));

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                nameValuePairs));
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                                responseHandler);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);
                        if (response.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Message Not Sent");
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };

            thread.start();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_booking, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

    static Context context;
    public static final String TAG = "Utils";
    public static final String UserName = "UserName";

    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

    public Utils(Context context) {
        Utils.context = context;
    }

    public SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences() {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(((ActionBarActivity) context)
                .getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
        Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + value);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getFromPreferences(String key) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
        String value = prefs.getString(key, "");
        if (value.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, key + " not found.");
            return "";
        }
        return value;
    }

    String getRegistrationId() {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION,
                Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion();
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    static int getAppVersion() {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void storeRegistrationId(String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
        int appVersion = Utils.getAppVersion();
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        Log.i(TAG, "Reg ID : " + regId);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getCurrentIPAddress() {
        return "http://192.168.0.101/";
    }

    public void showToast(final String txt) {
        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In my app user login as simple user or login as driver if user login and register with gcm and press booked button notification send to specific driver

Comment: your implementation seems fine. check in the backend, how and to which devices you are sending the notifications.

Comment: Make sure that your back end server app is sending the gcm to correct device or always to your device.When app registers to gcm device got a unique gcm id,that is used by the server to send notification to specific device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just because you are calling your own device id to get notified,Please check out the backend , all the registered users must have their own device id's . Make sure their is different device id generated while a new Registration happens.